# DbSet for interface-based model fails in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following model:

```
[Table(nameof(DataItem))]  
public partial class DataItem : IBasicDataItem
{
  public DataItem()
  {
    BasicQuantity = 5;
  }
}
```

I use this method to save data (insert or update):

```
public async Task SaveListAsync<TDbType>(List<TDbType> dataList, bool isNew) where TDbType : class
{
   if (isNew)
   {
      await context.Set<TDbType>().AddRangeAsync(dataList);
   }
   else
   {
     //get the set
     var dbSet = context.Set<TDbType>().Local; //exception!
     //context().Set<TDbType>().AttachRange(dataList); //works
   }
   await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

If I use the list with `AttachRange`, it works as expected.

Whenever I use the actual `DbSet`, it gives me the following exception:

> Cannot create a DbSet for `IBasicDataItem` because this type is not
>   included in the model for the context.

The interface is obviously missing but the actual type is there.

What is the difference? How could I make the second option work?

Comment: why are you using `.Local`?

Comment: Let make it clear. You are passing `IBasicDataItem` as `TDbType` argument of this generic method? If yes, any `Set` method should fail, not only the one used with `.Local` property.  You should pass the actual class, not the interface, and constrain the method if needed.

Comment: Unrelated, but you shouldn't be using `AddRangeAsync`, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addrangeasync?view=efcore-2.1) for more info.

Comment: @DavidG Actually every interface passes `class` constraint. I guess because `class` seems to mean  `!struct`.

Comment: Regarding `Set<T>()` method, looks like the EF Core implementation of `DbSet<T>` checks if the `T` is actually an entity class lazily and throws exception at that time, rather than immediately. `Local` is one of the things triggering that check, querying is another. And `Add` / `AddRange` etc. might use back door :(

Comment: @IvanStoev So I can't use the actual type? How does AddRange work?

Comment: @Nestor See my last comment. Most likely some methods are bypassing the verification. May be because they operate on object instances, so they can use `GetType()` to get the actual type. While all `Local` and `IQueryable` have is the generic type argument.